# Relay Modern: delete record in optimisticUpdater

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

In my app I have a `mutation` where I want to use the `optimisticUpdater` to update the view before the server response. For that I need to remove some records from a list into the relay store, like that:

```
optimisticUpdater: storeProxy => {
  storeProxy.delete(recordDataID)
}
```

The problem is that relay don't **remove** the record, but it transforms the record in `null`.
This can be annoying because I have to filter the list every time I use it in my app.

Some one know how can I **remove** the record ?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove your records from the list

```
optimisticUpdater: (store) => {
    const listOfRecords = store.getRoot().getLinkedRecords('list')
    const newList = listOfRecords.filter(record => record.getDataID() !== recordDataID)
    store.getRoot().setLinkedRecords(newList, 'list')
}
```

In this example I assume your list is placed at the root of your graph

Comment: Any chance you can explain why this is the case? What is the purpose of `store.delete(id)` then?

Comment: `store.delete(id)` is a valid method for removing items from the store, you just need to account for it on your list view. You could either `.filter()` out records that are null, or show some text like "This record has been deleted" `if record === null`

Answer (score 2):

If you decorate your query with `@connection`, then you can use the `ConnectionHandler` to easily remove records:

```
const query = graphql`query WidgetListQuery {
    widgets(first: 10) @connection(key: "WidgetList_widgets") {
        ...
    }
}`
```

```
optimisticUpdater(store) {
    const widgets = ConnectionHandler.getConnection(store.getRoot(), 'WidgetList_widgets');
    ConnectionHandler.deleteNode(widgets, deleted_widget.id)
}
```